# SensKeys on a window

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

i was programming an hack for a game in Visual basic, i want simulate a keypress with the code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    SendKeys.Send("a")
End Sub
```

In my window game didn't work, but in other windows such as chrome or a test textbox work, why?

Answer (score 0):

if this is not a flash game , you can get the process of the game by:

```
 Dim TheGame as Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("YourGame")(0)
```

get the handle of the game window:

```
Dim Handle As IntPtr = TheGame.MainWindowHandle
```

and then use sendmessage function to send the keys to the window:

```
SendMessage(Handle, 258, PUT KEY HERE, 0)
```

for example - instead of the "PUT KEY HERE" type:
&H41 (is "A")

you can find the keys list here:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/VirtualKeys.html


the user32.dll sendmessage function:

```
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                 (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
```

Edit:
if the code is not working change the 258 (wm_char) in the sendmessage  to 256(wm_keydown)
note:sendkeys sends keys to the current active window, and you should try to use pinvoke functions first and if you don't have any choice then use sendkeys.
Recommendation:
explore the functions: postmessage,sendmessage,setforegroundwindow and also explore spy++ tool :).

Comment: I used yout code, when i compile appear this message http://gyazo.com/1e44cb86687bc755868a8d03ee8dc36c

Comment: if the game is not runing you will get this exception , you can add if condition before the "Process.GetProcessesByName", If Process.GetProcessesByName("YourGame").length > 0 Then

Comment: But game is running this is the problem